Как получит определённую переменную в конструкторе?
Пытаюсь получить переменную в конструкторе, но выдаёт ошибку.
        for (int i = 0; i < typeof(TokenType).GetConstructors().Length; i++)
        {
            TokenType tokenType = typeof(TokenType).GetConstructors()[i];
        }

Ошибка:

Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo" в "TokenType".

Как преобразовать?

Подумайте логически, у вас есть вот класс (как я понял, он ваш) TokenType, вы берете информацию его конструкторов через GetConstructors(), вот теперь подумайте, "информация конструктора" является вашим типом? Далее, вам нужные "переменные" (я так понимаю речь о параметрах, что в скобках после имени класса), ок, вы взяли конструктор, а где получение этих параметров? Наверно надо вызвать еще GetParameters(), получить тем самым информацию о параметре, из которой уже можно вытянуть Name и ParameterType, но опять, это не будет TokenType`.

const TokenType tokenType = это же не JavaScript, уберите const.

А зачем вам рефлексия, если не секрет? Есть хорошие шансы, что вы пытаетесь сделать что-то не то.

Я пытаюсь из конструктора при помощи for получить все переменные с типом TokenType
